# Is there a simple way to tell if an arbitrary string is well-formed JSON in Android?

Tags: android, json

We're writing an app that communicates with an internet-based CMS in JSON.  Unfortunately, some types of network connection e.g. through public Wifi have a web gateway that they require you to go through before you can use the net normally.  This means we are trying to JSON parse an HTML webpage.  I would expect it to throw an exception stating that the HTML isn't well-formed JSON but instead it tries to parse it, runs out of memory and collapses.

I have looked through the Android JSON functions and can't find a function that simply tells you if a string is JSON or not.  Is there such a function?  If not, am I simply going to have to write something heuristic to trap obviously non-JSON strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Header contentType = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Type");
if (contentType.getValue().compareToIgnoreCase("application/json") != 0) {
    // response is not JSON
    response = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The exact way to check for its well-formed JSON is to create a JSONObject based on the string returned from HTTP Response. JSONException will occurs if the resulted string is not a well-formed JSON.

I don't know why you're running out of memory too soon. Is it because the returned string is very large? If so, you can take the advantages of the JSON format. Check the first character of the string. If it's `{` then it's **probably** JSON. Otherwise, it's not a JSON.

Please note the word **"probably"**. It's because I don't know whether the server sometimes gives you another response with `{` as its first character and it's not a JSON. You decide.

You should read a JSON string formatted [here](http://json.org/).

Comment: It is usually pretty large—it's a full webpage. Not in itself enough to cause an OOM but I think the parser is flaking out under the pressure.  I like the initial brace sanity check idea though—at any rate it's unlikely we'll get anything except HTML, JSON and binaries through so this may be good enough!  By the way, we are trapping JSONException already in anticipation of this kind of problem so presumably a short enough non-JSON string would throw that.

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking the `Content-Type` HTTP header of the response. If it is returning HTML, it will be `text/html`. If it is returning JSON, it will be `application/json`.

Answer (score 2):

Telling you whether this is valid JSON or  not would require complete parsing. Android bundles vanilla JSON parse working on like XML DOM parser - those parsers try to construct complete syntax tree in  memory - thus they are prone to

- low performance
- heavy memory usage

I would suggest to use pull parser like  GSON  - there is also some kind of databinding which comes handy if you need objects out of your JSON or just strupped down binary ( 16KB ) to just parse ( I use it with my own databinding layer: https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer )

Comment: I use it to pull and parse highscores for my games - 2000 JSON entries. Parsing on startup takes about 1 second